# Qual è il significato di "tenersi su" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Gli occhiali d'oro*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Sapeva che *sapevamo*? Forse no, forse su questo punto si illudeva ancora. Nel suo contegno, comunque, nell'educato e preoccupato riserbo che si sforzava di mantenere, era fin troppo facile leggere il fermo proposito di comportarsi come se niente di sé fosse mai trapelato in città. Per noi, soprattutto per noi, lui doveva restare il dottor Fadigati di una volta, quando, da bambini,  vedevamo il suo largo viso, seminascosto dietro il tondo specchio frontale, piegarsi e incombere sul nostro viso. Se al mondo esistevano  delle persone con le quali lui dovesse cercare di **tenersi su**, queste eravamo proprio noi.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "tenersi su" in questo brano? Ho cercato alle voci "tenere" e "su" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovarne il significato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Tenersi su*** in questo contesto significa darsi un tono, non lasciarsi andare, non perdere il contegno adeguato ad una persona che svolge il lavoro di medico.

Era necessario che si comportasse come se niente fosse, soprattutto per non perdere l’autorevolezza e la considerazione accumulata negli anni da parte della gente.